# What is the format of Indian mobile number

Tags: mobile, number-formatting, mobile-country-code

I know that a mobile number is composed of 
Mcc+mnc+lac+cellid as per 
http://www.opencellid.org/

but now how can i divide it for an Indian mobile number ? as per 
1) MCC (Mobile country code)
2)MNC (Mobile decimal code)
3)Lac (Local area code)
4)cell id ( cell id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSI) explains the structure quite well. There should be no problem identifying the parts.

Note however that some of the parts you mention (Cell Id, LAC, ...) are *NOT* part of the IMSI. The IMSI an immutable identier of the subscriber but LAC, cell-id and etc are clearly quite volatile depending where the subscriber actually is.

Comment: Are you sure that IMSI is immutable? Because as Wikipedia IMSI = MCC + MNC + MSIN and as I understand MSIN can be change by the provider when being e.g. in another country romaing?

Comment: @david I'm Sure. The subscriber ID does not change when roaming.